# Completely disable ng-pick-datetime calendar input in an Angular form

Tags: angular, datepicker, calendar

I'm working on an Angular project which has a calendar picker in a form. I chose 'ng-pick-datetime' ([npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime](http://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime)) to get cross-browser calendar compatibility.

I've succesfully implemented the calendar. The issue is how to completely disable/block it (I need this when certain user is in the form). What happens right now is that the input field correctly gets disabled when [disabled] is true in the template tag, so no Date can be written in there.

BUT, **there is a cross at the right part of the field that never gets disabled**, so the user is always able to click that cross and erase the Date, setting the input at null, whenever the calendar is disabled or not.

My html template code is as follows:

```
<div class="input-control col-sm-6" [class.has-error]="endDate.invalid && endDate.dirty">
   <label class="control-label" for="endDate">End date *</label>
   <owl-date-time
      [(ngModel)]="data.endDate"
      [dateFormat]="'DD-MM-YYYY'"
      [inputId]="'endDate'"
      [placeHolder]="'dd-mm-aaaa'"
      [type]="'calendar'"
      [autoClose]="'true'"
      id="endDate"
      name="endDate"
      #endDate="ngModel"
      [disabled]="!paramsService.isSolicitante()"
      required="required">
    </owl-date-time >
</div>
```

If any other code / info is needed I'll provide it quickly, but I think it's mainly a template problem.

[Screenshot ng-pick-datetime cross](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcSKH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is `[hideClearButton]` property, can be set using `boolean` in the [docs](https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker):

> When specified to true, the picker's input clear icon would be hidden.